# angular/material2 md-card responsive images

Tags: angular, angular2-material

Using angular/material2 how do I set **img md-card-image** to be responsive on height. Here is the example taken from https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/card/README.md

I want to set the image height to 200px and expect to scale the width to this.

```
<md-card>
   <md-card-header>
      <img md-card-avatar src="path/to/img.png">
      <md-card-title>Header title</md-card-title>
      <md-card-subtitle>Header subtitle</md-card-subtitle>
   </md-card-header>
   <img md-card-image src="path/to/img.png">
   <md-card-content>
      <p>Here is some more content</p>
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

and here is an example
http://plnkr.co/edit/DE8O7UYKid2NhpkiRWEF?p=preview

I tried to wrap my img tag around a relative container and giving for the image absolute position, but still is not the desired result:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ncJypD9NTeHqkcRA8TFb?p=preview

Comment: Can you add a starting point in code, please.

Comment: I will make an example!

Comment: Would you consider placing the image as a background image, instead of `<img>` element? If so, you'll have a lot of options for playing with the image position, and size...

Comment: I jut tried as css background but I still have the border problem on the sides.

Comment: try using https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Comment: Together with flex-layout, I got the best results by setting the md-card height instead of the image height, and let the image height scale to the available space in the md-card